# Implement the same function in AS2 for an Array

Tags: actionscript-2

I have an array, and I would like to make a function onRelease for all of the array positions.

The code would be like:

```
pick = new Array(2,3,4);
var botoes1:MovieClip = lev.attachMovie("block", "block_"+lev.getNextHighestDepth(), lev.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:550, _y:1*22});
_root.botoes1.gotoAndStop(pick[1]);
var botoes2:MovieClip = lev.attachMovie("block", "block_"+lev.getNextHighestDepth(), lev.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:550, _y:2*22});
_root.botoes2.gotoAndStop(pick[2]);
var botoes3:MovieClip = lev.attachMovie("block", "block_"+lev.getNextHighestDepth(), lev.getNextHighestDepth(), {_x:550, _y:3*22});
_root.botoes3.gotoAndStop(pick[3]);

for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    _root['botoes'+i].onRelease() = Function () {

    }
}
```

but it doesn't work this way...
and if possible, how can I make the MovieClip declaring for all the buttons in an for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple syntax errors there, here's what this line should look like:

```
_root['botoes' + i].onRelease = function()
{
    // Function body.
    //
}
```

Your previous code was trying to assign the result of `_root['botoes' + i].onRelease()` (which would have been `undefined`) to the result of `Function()` (which would have been a Function object).